# Import module using Manim

Tags: python, manim

I am trying to import a class from another file for a manim animation, however when executing the manim animation it is not possible to load my module. How to troubleshoot **without** a change in sys.path?

```
# padroes.py
from manimlib.imports import *

class Explora():
    LOGO = "\\vec{E}\\hspace{-1mm}\\times\\hspace{-1mm}\\vec{p}\\mathcal{L}0\\mathbb{R}a"
    # Cores utilizadas
    APATITA = "#43bfca"
    PAPOULA = "#dc6a40"
    STARSHIP = "#F2E33A"
    # Tempos
    TEMPO_LONGO = 5
    TEMPO_MEDIO = 2
    TEMPO_CURTO = 1.5
```

```
# test.py
from padroes import Explora

class Teste(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        TexMobject('JUST A TEST')
```

Both files are in the **same directory**, from where I execute the command
`manim test.py` resulting in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ariel/.local/bin/manim", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ariel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/manimlib/__init__.py", line 9, in main
    config = manimlib.config.get_configuration(args)
  File "/home/ariel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/manimlib/config.py", line 155, in get_configuration
    module = get_module(args.file)
  File "/home/ariel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/manimlib/config.py", line 150, in get_module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "teste.py", line 2, in <module>
    from padroes import Explora
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'padroes'
```

Comment: I tried running your code.  I don't have any problem if I run it with `python test.py`.  I tried it with both Python 3.7 and 3.9.  If I run it with `manim test.py`, then I get the same error you do.  This seems like a big time clue.  I don't know anything about the `manim` executable, but clearly, it is executing your code with a different environment setup, and that setup is not allowing your `test.py` file to import your `padroes.py` file.

Comment: Yeah, I can't see any other way but to add my current directory to the python path, but since I need to distribute the code to other people, changing them would be difficult

Comment: There's no reason that you can't have your code change `sys.path` prior to doing any imports.  You shouldn't have to require a change to the end user's environment.  We do this in production all the time.  In fact, we have a simple but effective system that works quite well.  It only assumes a static source tree layout and can describe how any project can find all of our submodules throughout our source repo quite easily.  The one important feature of it is that it only assumes a relative layout.  It doesn't require hard-coding the root path to the source tree.  I'd be happy to share that.

Comment: I was just looking at Manim.  It's a cool package.  I wasn't able to find much in their docs that discuss the underlying Python environment.  One thing I did see is a suggestion that you can run your code via the `python` binary rather than the `manim` binary.  What I saw was this: `python3 -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl`.  I'm not sure how your sample maps to that. I wonder if it might help to run your code this way.  You could create a script so you didn't have to type all that every time you run your code.

Comment: Now that I realize I'm having problems with ```python3```. I will solve this and try to execute it that way. I appreciate if you share the system you mentioned. I'm a student and I always like to see how things are done in production.

Comment: I am doing these animations in a project to help other students better visualize mathematics. If you want to know more we have a [Github](https://github.com/Explora-FT/Animacoes-Manim)